# gparted won't boot from liveCD

Tags: linux, boot, livecd

Fedora 12

2.6.32.9-70.fc12.i686

I downloaded the gparted iso and burnt it to a CD.

```
gparted-live-0.5.2-1
This GParted Live was created by:
create-gparted-live -l en -b u -e e -d sid -m http://free.nchc.org.tw/debian -s http://free.nchc.org.tw/debian-security -g http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core -n 2.6.32-3 -i 0.5.2-1
```

The files and folders:

```
isolinux
live
syslinux
COPYING
GParted-Live-Version
```

I put the disk in and reboot. Nothing happens. I just get a flashing cursor in the top left hand corner. I then have to switch of the power button to get it to reboot. I have done this a number of time and the results are the same.

Can anyone tell me how to boot from the gparted liveCD?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: you're sure you grabbed a bootable ISO?  did you verify the download?  did you verify the burn?  did you try burning again?  did you try burning at a slower speed?

Comment: I did verify the burn was successfull. However, I will burn again just to be sure.

Comment: I have downloaded the same iso and burnt it to a different disk. I still experienced the same problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Fedora Live CD and install gparted. Obviously it will be a volatile installation but will be usable.